# Is it possible to run Google Chrome in kiosk mode on Snow Leopard?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, operating-systems, kiosk

Is it possible to run Google Chrome in kiosk mode on OS X, specifically Snow Leopard?

I cannot find a way of doing so currently. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Considering [this forum post](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=12bde481a208c4ca&hl=en) popped up on Google's help, I'm assuming a true kiosk mode hasn't been added. However, it is apparently possible to acheive some level of kiosk mode with on Windows with:

```
chrome.exe --kiosk http://www.google.com
```

On OS X, you could probably use:

```
open /Applications/Chrome.App --kiosk http://www.google.com
```

I can't test it because I'm not on a Mac right now, but it may do the trick.

Comment: I under stand how to do this on windows through the run command, but where would I run this command from on a mac to test? Thanks

Comment: In OS X, go to Applications > Utilities > Terminal. This is equivalent to a Windows Run... command.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this out and then it wouldn't let me exit kiosk mode. I had to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to get out of Google Chrome. Save the following to a script, something like `ChromeKiosk.sh` and `chmod +x ChromeKiosk.sh` to get it to run.

```
#!/bin/bash
open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args --kiosk http://www.google.com.au
```

This will open Google Chrome to the `http://www.google.com.au` webpage. Change it as you need. Copy and paste the rest of the script

If you want to turn it into an AppleScript so that you can create an application that can in turn be automatically run each time the computer reboots to a default specified user, use the following code and when you save the script, change it's type to Application

```
do shell script "/bin/bash open \"/Applications/Google Chrome.app\" --args --kiosk"
```

It's requires the `\` *(escape sequence)* before the `"` because of the way the shell reads the spacing between the words **Google** and **Chrome** in the filename. You can also write it as

```
do shell script "/bin/bash open /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app --args --kiosk"
```

It's just that I've never favoured the look of seeing a escape before a backslash. It's too messy. Stick with either the BashScript option at the top or use the 1st of 2 AppleScript lines and save it as an Application type.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Vista and Windows 7 only:

Right click Desktop, create a shortcut.

Target:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -kiosk http://google.com/
```

Start In:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Comment: The author asks for a Mac OS X solution.  This is the exact same command that was provided in Nov 2011.